# unable to initiate activity componentInfo

Tags: android, android-activity

I have seen many topics on it but the problem still remains. My application is pretty simple, I only have a main activity named PlayVideo which intiliazes a MediaPlayer streaming a video from an IPCAM. I have already replace in order the lib files in the java build path. I also have created a new AVD and cleaned the project.

```
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.c2s.playerfirst/com.c2s.player.PlayVideo}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.c2s.player.PlayVideo" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.c2s.playerfirst-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.c2s.playerfirst-1, /system/lib]]
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.c2s.player.PlayVideo" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.c2s.playerfirst-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.c2s.playerfirst-1, /system/lib]]
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
10-22 09:28:40.411: E/AndroidRuntime(1016):     ... 11 more
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.c2s.playerfirst/com.c2s.player.PlayVideo}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.c2s.player.PlayVideo" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.c2s.playerfirst-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.c2s.playerfirst-1, /system/lib]]
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.c2s.player.PlayVideo" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.c2s.playerfirst-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.c2s.playerfirst-1, /system/lib]]
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
10-22 10:05:56.052: E/AndroidRuntime(1039):     ... 11 more
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.c2s.playerfirst"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity

            android:name="com.c2s.player.PlayVideo"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Activity class :

```
public class PlayVideo extends Activity{

//private String  videoPath="http://192.168.0.157";
private String videoPath="http://50.73.56.89";

private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String videourl;
VideoView videoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(PlayVideo.this, "", "Buffering Video");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    PlayVideo();
}


private void PlayVideo(){
    try{
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        videoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(PlayVideo.this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

        Uri video = Uri.parse(videoPath);
        System.out.println(video);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);
        videoView.requestFocus();

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                System.out.println("********  BEGIN ONPREPARED ********");
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                videoView.start();
                System.out.println("******** END ONPREPARED ********");
            }
        });

    }catch(Exception e){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        System.out.println("Video Play Error : "+e.toString());
        finish();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Make sure your class is initiated..Also post some of your code for clear understanding..

Comment: I've edited with my activity class ;)

Comment: From your manifest file your package name is package="com.c2s.playerfirst" but in the activity declaration its shows android:name="com.c2s.player.PlayVideo".

Comment: I changed the name to com.c2s.playerFirst. Now I have nothing !

Comment: Means your activity is started.Now the problem lies in your video playing part..

Comment: OK thanks. BTW Eclipse debug doesn't work anymore. I could say Eclipse Debug mode buggued ah ah ! Would you know how to deal with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting bin and gen directory, clean project and make sure that in Build Path, under Order and Export tab all libraries are checked if you are using them in your application.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it's still the same. In order and export there are in the order : Android, Android private lib, Android dependancies, myproject/src, myproject/gen